# spring 5 does not create method findByFieldName that supports Pageable

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, dynamically-generated

I am trying to use the findByFieldName generated methods in the repository interface. I am getting this error at compile time:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property source found for type Article!
at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.<init>(PropertyPath.java:77) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.8.RELEASE.jar:na]
```

My Article model looks like this:

```
package com.infostream.models;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;

@Entity
@Table(name = "articles")
public class Article extends Base {

    private String ref_id;

    public String getRef_id() {
        return ref_id;
    }

    public void setRef_id(String ref_id) {
        this.ref_id = ref_id;
    }

    public Article() {

    }

    public Article(String source_id, String ref_id, String title, String subject, String description, String url) {
        this.source_id = source_id;
        this.ref_id = ref_id;
        this.title = title;
        this.subject = subject;
        this.description = description;
        this.url = url;
    }

    public String getSource_id() {
        return source_id;
    }

    public void setSource_id(String source_id) {
        this.source_id = source_id;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getSubject() {
        return subject;
    }

    public void setSubject(String subject) {
        this.subject = subject;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getUrl() {
        return url;
    }

    public void setUrl(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }

    @NotNull
    private String source_id;

    @NotNull
    private String title;

    private String subject;
    private String description;

    @NotNull
    private String url;
}
```

My interface which defined the findByFieldName looks like this:

```
package com.infostream.repositories;

import org.springframework.data.domain.Page;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable;
import org.springframework.data.repository.PagingAndSortingRepository;

import com.infostream.models.Article;
import java.lang.String;

public interface ArticleRepositoryImpl extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Article, Long> {
    Page<Article> findAll(Pageable pageRequest);

    Page<Article> findBySource_id(String source_id, Pageable pageable);
}
```

As you can see in the model above, source_id is defined in the model.

On my main class that runs the application, i have defined the place for the jpa repositories.

```
package com.infostream;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.infostream.repositories")
public class InfoStreamSpringBootApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {       
        SpringApplication.run(InfoStreamSpringBootApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Does anyone have a source example of how they achieve this?

Comment: First make sure to use proper get/set method naming convention before asking the question.

Comment: spring-data-jpa relies heaviliy on standard naming conventions. You chose not to respect them. Don't put undersores in your variables and method names

Comment: oh ok that makes sense, will go try that, thanks

Comment: wow, thanks a lot, that solved my issue :)